# Line chart using plotly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, plotly, linechart

The following is my dataframe.

[image]

How can I create a line using plotly where x-axis contains the years and y-axis contains the production value of that specific year

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this code should do the job:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Minerals':['Nat. Gas'],
              '2013':[5886],
              '2014':[5258],
              '2015':[5214],
              '2016':[5073],
              '2017':[5009],})

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=df.columns[1:],
                                y=df.loc[0][1:]))
fig.show()
```

and you get:

[image]